# Azure Web App Service alert for 403 is not working

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring

I'm trying to play around with the Azure web app service monitoring alert. I have configured an alert for if HTTP status 403 greater than 5 over the last 5 minutes, it will send email to my mailbox. 
[image]
I then stopped my web app instance and keep refreshing my page for more than 5 times. And I waited for more than 5 minutes, still see no alert email in my gmail.
I'm wondering, is this the right way to test the alert mechanism? Or am I missing other configuration?

Answer (score 1):

> I then stopped my web app instance and keep refreshing my page for more than 5 times

If you stop the web app, it would not monitor http status in real time. The alert in web app would not work. Please keep the web app in the running status.

[image]

Once the http 403 consistently over 5 count  in 5 minutes, it would send me an email to alert.

To get 403 error, you could operate somehting that you don't have permissions. You could use SAS permissions to achieve instead of stopping web app to get 403. Every time you trigger the 403 error , the count chart would also increase. You could check the count chart every minute(the data updates [every minute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/insights-alerts-portal)).

You could also test other http status, like 200(OK),404(Not Found),401(Unauthorized). I test http 404, just enter the wrong url and refresh the pages over 5 times. It works fine on my side.

[image]

Comment: If my answer is helpful, please don't forget to mark it as answer. Thanks.